# Customize position of a container flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place my image in the top centre of my screen, under the appbar. I managed to move it vertically, but can't seem to move it horizontally.

```
Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 10),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0, top: 100.0, right: 100.0, bottom: 100.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
```

I have tried everything (mainAxisAlignment, crossAxisAlignment, margin, padding). None of them seem to work.

The following is the screen that I have currently. I need to bring the logo to the top centre:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try align. Try this

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I tried first in my code then posted the answer, thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have more control over the placement of the image use the code below. change the value of the Alignment(x, y) to select the exact location of the image.

x controls the x-Axis (vertical placement) and the value must be between -1 (top) and 1 (bottom). the same thing applies for y. it controls  the  y-Axis and its value must be between -1 (far left) and 1 ( far right).

The center is Alignment (0, 0). You can use any number between -1 and 1 such as (-0.8, 0.3) or (1, -0.4).

Make sure to place the image inside a container that fill the space you'd like to use. In the example below, the container width is equal to the screen width, and the container height is equal to the screen height minus the app bar height.

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("demo"),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Container(
      //the container width is equal to the screen width
      //and its height is equal to the screen height minus the app bar height
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight,
      child: Align(
         //Alignment(-1, -1) place the image at the top & far left
         // you can change the value of x and y to any number between -1 and 1
        alignment: Alignment(-1, -1), 
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you!! This will come handy in the future ^_^